# How to use nginx http/2 server push to send a json payload from an API call to the client

Tags: nginx, http2, server-push

I have a simple nginx config like the one below, and I need to return a certain version of a json payload and push it to the browser along with the requested `demo.html` when the client makes the request for `/demo.html?version={some_version}`. I have a REST endpoint that I can use to get the proper json. However I can't find any documentation on how to make this happen.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location = /demo.html?version=x {
        http2_push payload_x.json; # need to make a call to get a json and push
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to server push a json payload dynamically in nginx?

If so how one would do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s possible to push a JSON file. And yes you would do it like you said, but make sure you give it the full path (so must at least begin with a /):

```
http2_push /payload_x.json;
```

To set out the x variable based on the version query param you should be able to use `$arg_version`:

```
http2_push /payload_$arg_version.json;
```

Not you will still need to request the JSON File from the browser, but then it will pick up the pushes resource rather than requesting it all the way from the servers.